# jQuery - Load json in a XML load Event

Tags: jquery, xml, json, load

i have a xml file like this

```
<users>
    <user>
        <name>LOREM</name>
        <pic>LOREM</pic>
        <post>www.URL.com/info.json</post>
    </user>
    <user>
        <name>LOREM</name>
        <pic>LOREM</pic>
        <post>www.URL.com/info.json</post>
    </user>
</users>
```

i parse this xml with jquery so:

```
var data = {};
$.get('xmlfile.xml', function(xml){
    var oXML = $(xml);

    oxml.find('user').each(function(i){
        data[i].name = $(this).attr('name');
        data[i].pic = $(this).attr('pic');
        data[i].post = /* i must load a json file with all posts here*/
    });

});
```

the posts are in a extern json file. i have tried to load the json on load xml like this

```
var data = {};
$.get('xmlfile.xml', function(xml){
    var oXML = $(xml);

    oxml.find('user').each(function(i){
        data[i].name = $(this).attr('name');
        data[i].pic = $(this).attr('pic');
        data[i].post = $.getJSON($(this).attr('post'), function(data){
            retrun data;
        });
    });

});
```

But it dosnt work. The value of `data[i].post` is null. do you have an idea for loading json on load xml ?

Answer (score 2):

`$.getJSON` is asynchronous because AJAX is asynchronous. You could access the results of of an AJAX call only inside the `success` callback. In your example you are attempting to assign the return value of the `$.getJSON` call to the `data[i].post` variable. But this cannot possibly work because the value could be available much later, only after the AJAX call succeeds.

So you could invert your logic a little bit:

```
$.get('xmlfile.xml', function(xml) {
    var oXML = $(xml);

    oxml.find('user').each(function(i) {
        var index = i;
        $.getJSON($(this).attr('post'), function(res) {
            data[index].name = $(this).attr('name');
            data[index].pic = $(this).attr('pic');
            data[index].post = res;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: top solution i have a other question. Sometimes is the json by users equal. i want create a function for this case:
if the json is loaded dont load json more and take over the jason from the over user. how can do it?

Answer (score 1):

### The main problem is that `getJSON` is asyncronous

Your `post` properties in `data` are `null` because there are two things you're doing wrong here:

1. `getJSON` is asyncronous so it gets your data after your `.each` is already executed
2. `getJSON` doesn't return data but rather `jqXHR` object

Try changing it this way:

```
var data = []; // you likely want an array and not an object
var counter = 0;

$.get('xmlfile.xml', function(xml) {

    var oXML = $(xml);

    oxml.find('user').each(function(i) {
        var me = $(this);

        data.push({
            name: me.attr('name'),
            pic: me.attr('pic'),
            post: null
        });

        // increment counter
        counter++;

        $.getJSON(me.attr('post'), (function(index) {
            return function(data) {
                data[index].post = data;
                if (!--counter) // when it reaches ZERO
                {
                   setTimeout(function() {
                       // all JSONs have loaded now continue with your stuff
                   }, 0);
                }
            };
        })(i));
    });

});
```

Above code also detects when all JOSN objects have loaded so you can continue processing.

But apart from that it works this way:

1. it gets the XML
2. when XML is received it iterates through `user` elements and prepares `data` objects and pushes them into array
3. with each object it issues an Ajax call to get JSON data as well
4. each successful call to JSON then populates correct `data` object's `post` property and decreases `counter`
5. when counter reaches zero an additional function is being queued where you can put code that should execute after everything's loaded and done.

If your JSON requests can also fail, then I suggest to use `$.ajax` instead of `getJSON` so you can also provide `error` function inside of which you'd also decrement `counter`. Otherwise it wouldn't reach zero if only successes are being counted.